# How to prevent Texture Stretching

Tags: texturing, materials, image, coordinates, texture-coordinates

As seen in the first picture the image texture (with Texture coordinates) works ok

[image]

But when i try to move the image texture up the wall this happens

[image]

is there a way to fix this i tried to rotate the Controler plane and it did prevent the stretch but made it so the texture was in 2 places as seen below

[image]

is there a diffrent way to fix this ?

Comment: a way to fix this would be to use a UV unwrap, I supposed this is not waht you're using? But maybe share your file (don't forget to pack your image)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Does it solve your issue? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249069/2214

Comment: it solves my other problem but not this one still thx for the help.

Comment: How did it fail? If you are still looking for answer share your blend ... Or use uv texturing as suggested.