# Problems with Textures

Tags: texturing, image, texture-coordinates, vector-mapping

Hello i have 2  problems with textures

1.i use (Texture Coordinates) with image texture on cube (or any mesh that isn't flat plane). the texture is in 2 places at the same time how to fix this

[image]

[image]

here is a file with the problem
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can avoid that

Comment: It seems to be duplication of https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249069/2214 ... second issue seems to be solved with the same post.